# Start mp4box using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, process

What is the syntax for executing mp4box inside c# code base to produce a dash file mpd I have been trying with the following parameters and it always seems to fail

```
-dash 20000 -frag 2000 -rap myfile.mp4
```

This is while using the .net Process class

the code i was using is this

this is the mpd that is being produced but i expected something with segmenturl

```
<MPD type="OnDemand" xmlns="urn:3GPP:ns:PSS:AdaptiveHTTPStreamingMPD:2009">
   <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
     <Title>Media Presentation Description for file          C:\Users\solo\Documents\VisualStudio2013\Projects\PressPause\PressPause.Web\bin\Media\10-Commands and Key Bindings - Copy.mp4 generated with GPAC </Title>
        </ProgramInformation>
           <Period start="PT0S" duration="PT0H3M7.40S">
  <Representation mimeType="video/mp4" width="1280" height="720" sampleRate="48000" numChannels="2" lang="eng" startWithRAP="true" bandwidth="361929">
          <SegmentInfo duration="PT10.00S">
            <InitialisationSegmentURL sourceURL="C:\Users\solo\Documents\VisualStudio2013\Projects\PressPause\PressPause.Web\bin\Media\10-Commands and Key Bindings - Copy_dash.mp4" range="0-1324"/>
              <Url range="1324-370839"/>
                  <Url range="370839-974843"/>
                    <Url range="974843-1524423"/>
                      <Url range="1524423-2169652"/>
    <Url range="2169652-2745401"/>
    <Url range="2745401-3352882"/>
    <Url range="3352882-3803846"/>
    <Url range="3803846-4200226"/>
    <Url range="4200226-4585911"/>
    <Url range="4585911-4956675"/>
    <Url range="4956675-5333450"/>
    <Url range="5333450-5721755"/>
    <Url range="5721755-6075877"/>
    <Url range="6075877-6402334"/>
    <Url range="6402334-6752013"/>
    <Url range="6752013-7124392"/>
    <Url range="7124392-7474571"/>
    <Url range="7474571-8180323"/>
    <Url range="8180323-8478209"/>
   </SegmentInfo>
  </Representation>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

can i still use this by using the range header in javascript to describe the different file segments

Comment: Try to execute mp4box on the command prompt first (cmd.exe). Does it run there?

Comment: Yes it does but when I do it using c# I get 2 input names specified error or it starts the process to dash the file but then throws an error saying cannot access dash file i/0 error I think it's the pay I am passing in the parameters that is wrong

Comment: Spaces within paths is a common pitfall. Try with paths that have no spaces.

Comment: i have remove the spaces and i get both the mpd file and the dash mp4 file but they are all 0 bytes in size

Comment: SOLVED!wrong combination with in my if statement was causing the files to be overwritten works now thanks alot @helb